# GSAP timeline over element

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

im try to fire timeline when a li it's hover, so i create a var with my timeline, and with event.delegateTarget to find children and not all with .CLASS

this is my code

```
$(".gb-help-list ").on('mouseover', 'li', function (e) {
console.log('mouse');
var tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.to($(event.delegateTarget).find('.line-help'), 2, {width: '100px', ease: Power4.easeOut})
        .to(".line-top", 2, {width: '100%', ease: Power4.easeOut}, "-=1");
```

});

i don't see any error in console, but this : `o($(event.delegateTarget).find('.line-help'), 2, {width: '100px', ease: Power4.easeOut}`  doesn't fire....

anyone can helpme?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that delegateTarget method works, which as per jQuery's documentation seems fine, the only issue here is that the second line of the tween does not have an element to tween. You'll need to pass one to it, something similar to this:

```
$(".gb-help-list ").on('mouseover', 'li', function (e) {
console.log('mouse');
var tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.to($(event.delegateTarget).find('.line-help'), 2, {width: '100px', ease: Power4.easeOut})
        .to($(event.delegateTarget).find('.line-top'), 2, {width: '100%', ease: Power4.easeOut}, "-=1");
});
```